# How show interactive charts in a GTK window?

Tags: python, charts, highcharts, pygobject, bokeh

I need to do some charts and it'll be so much better if they are interactive. 
I want something like [that](http://www.highcharts.com/demo/line-basic). So I look for packages, and [Bokeh](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/) seems interesting.

But once I'll have my beautiful chart... How to insert it in a Gtk window?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebKitGtk](http://webkitgtk.org/) to embed web pages.